# Strange "spinning up" like sound coming from Macbook at regular interval, every 5-10 seconds or so

Tags: hardware

I noticed it a few days ago that whenever my laptop is open/on there is a strange, very brief spin-up sound coming from what seems like the left side. It happens at a very regular interval, about every 5 seconds.

I was able to record it, you can here it faintly 3 times here https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCYKC.jpg

Any help or advice is appreciated! Everything seems to work fine otherwise, its just really annoying.

Comment: Please tell us the exact macbook model you have.

Comment: MacBook Pro 15-inch, 2017 running 10.15.7

Comment: As this [repair video of a MacBook Pro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X8rCc1UqQHU) shows, it has a fan on the left and right side. And best guess is that what you are probably hearing is the fan spinning up and down as necessary, to keep the CPU and laptop cool. (To verify, you can install [mac fans control](https://crystalidea.com/macs-fan-control) that will display the fan speed in real time).